# how to edit json quickly

Tags: javascript, json, excel

I make a table in Excel with 1000 questions and when convert it on JSON, I get:

```
 [{
  "QUESTION": "61771",
  "ANSWERS": "2772718 ",
  "CORRECT": "1,2,3,4"
},
  {
    "ANSWERS": "7271717"
  },
  {
    "ANSWERS": "272727"
  },
  {
    "ANSWERS": "6271717"
  },
  {
    "QUESTION": "716171781",
    "ANSWERS": "6171717",
    "CORRECT": "1,2,3"
  },
  {
    "ANSWERS": "7171616"
  },
  {
    "ANSWERS": "287272"
  },
]
```

But I need before "QUESTION" all "ANSWERS" connect to one "ANSWERS" and make a massive on "CORRECT", like this:

```
    {
      "QUESTION":"LALALLA",
      "ANSWERS":["123214","123214","124214","12412414"]
      "CORRECT":[1,2,3,4]
    },
```

How can I quickly change/correct this JSON with js or other programming language?

[Excel table link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Blo3OuHF9wuMReoZxuBdTG34NHWsrolH/view)

Comment: Could you share your Excel table? (or at least an example)

Comment: @Nanoo [Table](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Blo3OuHF9wuMReoZxuBdTG34NHWsrolH/view)

Comment: *can I quickly change* is relative. In days, hours, minutes, seconds? Magic functions perhaps?

Comment: Try using this [online tool](http://beautifytools.com/excel-to-json-converter.php) (it worked for me with your Excel table)

Comment: @GetSet it's very important for me. My father wants to practice as quickly as possible)

Comment: @Nanoo with this tool I converted this excel table, but I want to correct this JSON

Answer (score 0):

In order to do this, you need a way to identify which answers are associated with which questions. Based on your sample data, this does not appear to be the case.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what's needed?

**code**

```
let arr = [{
  "QUESTION":"LALALLA",
  "ANSWERS":"123214",
  "CORRECT":"1,2,3,4",
},
{
  "ANSWERS":"123214"
},
{
  "ANSWERS":"124214"
},
{
  "ANSWERS":"12412414"
}];

arr[0].CORRECT = arr[0].CORRECT.split(',').map((ele) => {
  return parseInt(ele);
});

let answ = [];
arr.forEach((ele) => {
  answ.push(ele.ANSWERS);
});

arr[0].ANSWERS = answ;
```

**OUTPUT**

`console.log(arr[0])`

```
{
  "QUESTION": "LALALLA",
  "ANSWERS": [
    "123214",
    "123214",
    "124214",
    "12412414"
  ],
  "CORRECT": [
    1,
    2,
    3,
    4
  ]
}
```

Comment: Thanks you, but it don't works, when I convert to JSON a several questions, like this

Comment: sorry, on telephone it's so really hard to write, and i want to sleep. can you wait about an 8-9 hours when i check your answer?

Answer (score -2):

Convert that into pandas in python
pandas.read_json(name) and try using transpose, melt, and some other functions pandas offer.

Comment: While this might work., suggesting a another language does not answer the question. Also, you answer is very vague: _using transpose, melt, and some other functions pandas offer_  might not be intuitive to everyone.